# Linked List using classes and methods, OOP C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, linked-list

this is one of my first OOP projects and i do not understand what am i doing wrong. I have to make a class for a linked list with the functions written inside. I get this error at the simplest possible call of a constructor and i do not know why : Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
this was nullptr.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class Nod {
    int info;
    Nod* next;

    public:
        Nod() {
            info = 0;
            next = NULL;
        }
        Nod(int inf, Nod *p)
        {
            info = inf;
            next = p;
        }
        ~Nod() {
            delete[] next;
            info = -1;
        }
        void setInfo(int x) {
            info = x;
        }
        int getInfo() {
            return info;
        }
        void setNext(Nod *p) {
            next = p;
        }
        Nod* getNext(Nod x) {
            return x.next;
        };
};

class Lista {
    Nod* start;
    Nod* end;
    int unsigned size;

    public:
        Lista(int x) {                                    //Constructor
            size = 1;
            start->setInfo(x);
            start->setNext(NULL);
            end->setNext(NULL);
        }

        Lista(int x, int y) {               //Constructor
            start = new Nod;
            start->setInfo(y);
            Nod* NodCurent;
            start->setNext(NodCurent);
            NodCurent->setInfo(y);
            for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= size; i++)
            {
                Nod* NodUrmator;
                NodUrmator = new Nod;
                NodCurent->setNext(NodUrmator);
                NodUrmator->setInfo(x);
                end->setNext(NodUrmator);
                end = NodUrmator;
                Nod NodCurent(x, NodUrmator);
            }
        }

        ~Lista() {                                  //Destructor
            Nod *p = start->getNext(*start);
            Nod *aux;
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                aux = p;
                p = p->getNext(*p);
                delete aux;
            }
            start = end = NULL;
            size = 0;
        }

        void insert(int x) {                    //insert x at the end of the list
            if (size != 0)
            {
                Nod* newEnd = new Nod(x, NULL);
                //newEnd->setNext(NULL);
                //end->setInfo(x);
                end->setNext(newEnd);
                end = newEnd;
                size++;
            }
            else
            {
                Nod* aux;
                aux->setInfo(x);
                size = 1;
                start = end = aux;
            }
        }

        void insertAt(int x, int i) {            //insert x on position i
            if (i >= size)
            {
                Nod *p = new Nod(x, NULL);
                end->setNext(p);
                end = p;
                size++;
            }
            else if (i <= 0)
            {
                Nod* aux = new Nod(x, start);
                start = aux;
                size++;
            }
            else                                              
            {
                Nod* aux = start->getNext(*start);
                //aux->setNext(*(start->getNext));
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    start->setInfo(x);
                    start->setNext(aux);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                    {
                        aux = aux->getNext(*aux);
                    }
                    Nod aux1(x,aux);
                    size++;
                }
            }
        }

        int get(int i)                               //Return element from position i;
        {
            Nod* aux = start;
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                aux = aux->getNext(*aux);
            return aux->getInfo();
        }

        int length() {                               //Return size of list;
            return size;                                                         
        }
        Lista reverse()                              //Returneaza lista scrisă invers;
        {
            //IDK;
        }
        void removeFirst()                           //deletes first element;
        {
            if (size == 0)
                return;
            Nod *p = start->getNext(*start);
            delete start;
            start->setNext(p->getNext(*p));
            size--;
        }

        void removeLast()                            //deletes last element;
        {
            if (size == 0)
                return;
            if (size == 1)
                removeFirst();
            Nod *p = start->getNext(*start);
            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
                p = p->getNext(*p);
            p->setNext(NULL);
            delete end;
            end = p;
            size--;
        }

        void remove(int i)                           //deletes element from position i;
        {
            if (i <= 0)
                removeFirst();
            if (i >= size)
                removeLast();
            Nod *p = start->getNext(*start);
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                p = p->getNext(*p);

            Nod *aux = p->getNext(*p);
            Nod *deSters = aux;
            aux = aux->getNext(*aux);
            delete deSters;
            p->setNext(aux);
            size--;
        }

        bool hasDuplicates()                         //Checks if list has duplicates;
        {
            if (size <= 1)
                return false;
            int v[200];
            Nod *p = start->getNext(*start);
            for (int i = 1; i <= size && p->getNext(*p) != NULL; i++)
            {
                v[i] = p->getInfo();
                p = p->getNext(*p);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++)
                for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)
                    if ((i != j) && (v[i] == v[j]))
                        return true;
            return false;
        }

        bool has(int x)                              //Checks if list has element x;
        {
            if (size == 0)
                return false;
            Nod *p = start->getNext(*p);
            for (int i = 1; i <= size && p->getNext(*p) != NULL; i++)
            {
                if (p->getInfo() == x)
                    return true;
                p->getNext(*p);
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool isEmpty()                               //Checks if list is empty;
        {
            if (size == 0)
                return true;
            return false;
        };
};

int main()
{
    Lista L(3);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, `start` and `end` are unintialized when the `Lista(int)` constructor tries to call methods on them. And `NodCurent` is uninitialized when the `Lista(int, int)` constructor calls `start->setNext(NodCurent);`.Same with `aux` in `insert(int)`. There are many other bugs in this code, too. A linked list is a bad choice for learning OOP, it is one of the harder containers for beginners to implement correctly (there are TONS of beginner questions on SO about bad linked list implementations). Start with something simpler to learn from, and then build up from there.

Comment: You could easily narrow this down if you use your debugger.

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger? If not, this is a great time to learn. A debugger lets you see execution step by step and inspect variables, to show you what went wrong, (hopefully) when it goes wrong.

Comment: `delete[] next;` deletes an array. It is unlikely that `next` points to an array. You probably meant `delete next;` Note: Having a node delete the next node in the it's destructor is a dangerous thing to do when the Linked list class that holds the node also tries to delete all of the nodes.

Comment: @user4581301 A recursive destructor is just a bad thing to use, period, but especially so in a linked list that may potentially have a lot of nodes in it. A stack overflow error is not uncommon to encounter in that case. An iterative loop in a non-recursive destructor is much safer.

Comment: You also have to be extra careful when deleting any node that you don't accidentally destroy the rest of the list. When you remove a node from the list you must be absolutely certain that next pointer is nulled before deleting it.

Comment: BTW, you should measure your build time, then remove precompiled headers and build again.  Usually the difference is negligible for all but huge projects.  Precompiled headers add another level of complexity to your project.